# JSON iteration working halfway

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this code inside an AngularJS Service:

```
var products = [];

$http.get('http://www.......it/app/parse.php').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        products.push(data);
        console.log(products);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error("Error JSON")
        console.log(data);
});

return {
    all: function() {
        return products;
    },
    remove: function(chat) {
        products.splice(products.indexOf(chat), 1);
    },
    get: function(chatId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (products[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
                return products[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

The HTML is composed of a JSON log and an ng-repeat.

```
<pre>{{shoesItems.items | json}}</pre>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in shoesItems.items">
```

This is the result:

[image]

While if I change `products.push(data);` to `products.push(data[0]);` I can see the first image:

[image]

How do I show them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said on the comments of this answer, this won't work because then we lose the reference to the original products array. Try this:

`products.push.apply(products, data)`

It basically adds all the elements on data to the products array.

Comment: Right, that's because angular doesn't call `.all()` on every digest cycle, so if you change products reference, it's lost. Then just call `.push()` but looping through all the data. Or there was a way to concat without changing ref with `products.push.apply(products, data);`

Answer (score 1):

Your first result is an array of array, try to access the first object like  this,

```
<pre>{{shoesItems[0].items | json}}</pre>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in shoesItems[0].items">
```